# Unity3d StartCoroutine from another script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I have two C# scripts:
`ScriptOne` that contains `IEnumerator StartSmth(){...}` and `ScriptTwo`. How can i start coroutine `StartSmth()` from `ScriptTwo`?

Comment: From ScriptTwo you call a method in ScriptOne that starts the coroutine. Use GetComponent<ScriptOne>() to obtain a reference to the ScriptOne component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a more fleshed out version of LearnCocos2D's answer.

I am assuming your scripts live on different Game Objects (if not you can ignore referencing gameobject A in the code below). You need to do something like the following:

**Script1 on GameObject A**

```
public class Script1 : MonoBehaviour {

    void Start() {}
    void Update() {}

    public void MethodToCall(){
        //Start coroutine here
    }
}
```

**Script2 on GameObject B**

```
public class Script2 : MonoBehaviour{

    public GameObject gameObjA; //reference to the game object the other script lives on. (this can also be done dynamically)

    void Start(){
        //logic to call target method on Script1
        var script1 = gameObjA.GetComponent<Script1>();
        script1.MethodToCall();
    }

    void Update() {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is old, but it still pops up in my Google searches. Coroutines that live on a different game object can be started very easily.

public class ScriptTwo : MonoBehaviour {

```
[SerializeField] ScriptOne scriptOne;

void Start() { StartCoroutine(scriptOne.StartSmth()); }
```

}